# Show that $P_{U_1|V_1}=P_{U_2|V_2}$ and $P_{V_1|U_1}=P_{V_2|U_2}$ implies that $P_{U_1}=P_{U_2}$ and $P_{V_1}=P_{V_2}$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $(U_1,V_1)$ and   $(U_2,V_2)$ be two pairs of random variables, defined on the same measurable space, with correcsponding joint distributions $P_{U_1,V_1}$ and  $P_{U_2,V_2}$.

Now suppose the following two conditions:
\begin{align}
P_{U_1|V_1}(A|v)=P_{U_2|V_2}(A|v)
\end{align} 
for every measurable set $A$ and every $v$, and
\begin{align}
P_{V_1|U_1}(B|u)=P_{V_2|U_2}(B|u)
\end{align} 
for every measurable set $B$ and every $u$.

**Question:** Does this imply that marginals distributions are the same? That is, $P_{U_1}=P_{U_2}$ and $P_{V_1}=P_{V_2}$.

*Proof in discrete Case.*  Consider the case when random variables are discrete. Then, by Bayes rule

\begin{align}
P_{U_1|V_1}(u|v)=  \frac{P_{V_1|U_1}(v|u) P_{U_1}(u)}{P_{V_1}(v)}= \frac{P_{V_2|U_2}(v|u) P_{U_2}(u)}{P_{V_2}(v)}
\end{align} 
using that  $P_{V_1|U_1}(v|u)=P_{V_2|U_2}(v|u) $ we have that

\begin{align}
 \frac{P_{U_1}(u)}{P_{V_1}(v)}= \frac{ P_{U_2}(u)}{P_{V_2}(v)}
\end{align}

Summing over $u$ in above we have that
\begin{align}
P_{V_1}(v)=P_{V_2}(v)
\end{align} 
The same argument leads to  $P_{U_1}(v)=P_{U_2}(v)$.

**Question 2:**  How do this proof cleanly in a general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write $P(U_1 \in A) = E(E(1_A(U_1) \mid V_1)) = E(E(1_A(U_2) \mid V_2)) = P(U_2 \in A).$

**Ammend.** If the condition $P(U_1 \in A \mid V_1 = v) = P(U_2 \in A \mid V_2 = v)$ holds for all Borel $A$ and $v \in \mathbf{R}$ then, by uniqueness, $P(U_1 \in A \mid V_1)$ and $P(U_2 \in A \mid V_2)$ are, on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbf{P}),$ the same random variable, upto a $\mathbf{P}$-null set. Hence, their expectation on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbf{P})$ is the same. It is important to remember that the relation
$$E(X) = \int\limits_\Omega X d\mathbf{P} = \int\limits_\mathbf{R} x dP_X$$
is true for whatever random variable $X$ ("the change of measures formula").

Comment: Can I ask you something? I don't think this works. I get how you get the second equality.   How do you get the last equality? The outer most integral is with respect to the distribution of $V_1$  and not $V_2$.   In other words, you have $  \int E[ 1_A(U_2)|V_2=v]  dP_{V_1}(v)$ and the outer integral is not with respect to the distribution of $V_2$

Comment: You are very confused. All the random variables are defined on the same probability space, so I am integrating on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbf{P})$ and not on $\mathbf{R}.$

Comment: I see... thanks.